# Forwarding variadic arguments in std::enable_if via other function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

Following issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

    using namespace std;

    template <typename... Args>
    inline constexpr size_t variadicElementCounter(Args... args)
    {
        return sizeof...(args); // get num of arguments in the parameter pack
    }

    template <typename DataType, size_t SizeValue>
    class Sth
    {
    public:
         Sth()=default;
         ~Sth()=default;

        template<typename ... VariadicValues, std::enable_if_t<(variadicElementCounter(VariadicValues...)) == SizeValue> * = nullptr>
        Sth(VariadicValues && ... f_values) noexcept : m_arr{ std::move(f_values) ...}
        {

        }

    private:
        std::array<DataType,SizeValue> m_arr;
     };

int main()
{
   // arr= {1,2,3};
    Sth<int,3> something={1,2,3};

    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

The example can be executed here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1Qpj67BI

Trying to compile this class, the `VariadicValues...` (probably) breaks the compilation
What am I doing wrong (because I want to avoid calling `sizeof...(VariadicValues)` in the `enable_if` expression

Comment: Why do you need `variadicElementCounter` function? Why not just use `sizeof...(VariadicValues)`?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. It's not clear why you need any SFINAE at all here. I'm guessing `m_arr` is a `std::array`?

Comment: I've added a minimal redproducible example now

Comment: @mbed_dev - your (bigger) problem is that you call `variadicElementCounter()` with **types**, not with values. Suggestion: avoid `variadicElementCounter()` and directly use `sizeof...(VariadicValues)`. Alternative solution: rewrite `variadicElementCounter()` receiving types (`template <typename... Args>
inline constexpr std::size_t variadicElementCounter ()
 { return sizeof...(Args); }`) and call it only with types (`variadicElementCounter<VariadicValues...>()`).

Comment: @mbed_dev - Addendum: your constructor is a template one, so the references (`VariadicValues && ... f_values`) are forwarding references, not r-value references; so you have to use `std::forward()` (`m_arr{ std::forward<VariadicValues>(f_values) ...}`), not `std::move()`